# Subtraction in SQL - Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I'm trying to find the number of currentArtists in my database.

I thought a good way to do it was find the number of artists, find the number of artists with an 'end date', then subtract the non-current ones from the total.

Code:

```
SELECT COUNT(Name) AS NumberOfArtists,
COUNT(YearEnded) AS NumberEnded,
COUNT(COUNT(Name) - COUNT(YearEnded)) AS NumberOfCurrentArtists
FROM Artists;
```

I get the error:

> Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery.

I've looked at many other questions on stack overflow with the same error, but it seems to be a very broad error, I couldn't find what I was doing wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT  COUNT(Name) AS NumberOfArtists
      , COUNT(YearEnded) AS NumberEnded
      , COUNT(Name) - COUNT(YearEnded) AS NumberOfCurrentArtists
FROM    Artists;
```

You dont need to do count of the difference, it just doesn't make any sense.